# Adding an index column representing a repetition of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that I'd like to repeat several times, and I want to add in a new variable to index those repetitions. The best I've come up with is using `mutate` + `rbind` over and over, and I feel like there has to be an efficient dataframe method I could be using here.

Here's an example: `df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])` gives us the dataframe

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

I'd like to repeat that say 3 times, with an index that looks like this:

| x | y | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 |
| 3 | c | 2 |
| 1 | a | 3 |
| 2 | b | 3 |
| 3 | c | 3 |

Using the `rep` function, I can get the first two columns, but not the index column. The best I've come up with so far (using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)) is:

```
df2 <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(index = 1) %>% 
  rbind(df %>% mutate(index = 2)) %>% 
  rbind(df %>% mutate(index = 3))
```

This obviously doesn't work if I need to repeat my dataframe more than a handful of times. It feels like the kind of thing that should be easy to do using dataframe methods, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Grateful for any tips!

Comment: The `rep function has two modes the default mode is to copy the entire first argument. You just need the `each=3` parameter for the last column to repeat each item in the first argument 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code for as many data frames as you would like. You just have to set the `n` argument:

- `replicate` function takes 2 main arguments. We first specify the number of time we would like to reproduce our data set by `n`. Then we specify our data set as `expr` argument. The result would be a list whose elements are instances of our data set
- After that we pass it along to `imap` function from `purrr` package to define the unique `id` for each of our data set. `.x` represents each element of our list (here a data frame) and `.y` is the position of that element which amounts to the number of instances we created. So for example we assign value `1` to the first `id` column of the first data set as `.y` is equal to `1` for that and so on.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

replicate(3, df, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  imap_dfr(~ .x %>% 
         mutate(id = .y))

  x y id
1 1 a  1
2 2 b  1
3 3 c  1
4 1 a  2
5 2 b  2
6 3 c  2
7 1 a  3
8 2 b  3
9 3 c  3
```

In base R you can use the following code:

```
do.call(rbind, 
mapply(function(x, z) { 
  x$id <- z 
  x 
  }, replicate(3, df, simplify = FALSE), 1:3, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

  x y id
1 1 a  1
2 2 b  1
3 3 c  1
4 1 a  2
5 2 b  2
6 3 c  2
7 1 a  3
8 2 b  3
9 3 c  3
```

Comment: I like this, it's more efficient than my mutate+rbind method obviously, but if I need to repeat the same dataframe 100 times or 1000 times, there's still the problem of having to write out the dataframe's name over and over.

Comment: My pleasure. If you had any question about the solution let me know or in case part of it was unclear.

Comment: Great description.

Comment: It's my pleasure master Arun. I owe all the things I learned and learn to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rerun` to repeat the dataframe `n` times and add an `index` column using `bind_rows` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

n <- 3
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
bind_rows(rerun(n, df), .id = 'index')

#  index x y
#1     1 1 a
#2     1 2 b
#3     1 3 c
#4     2 1 a
#5     2 2 b
#6     2 3 c
#7     3 1 a
#8     3 2 b
#9     3 3 c
```

In base R, we can repeat the row index 3 times.

```
transform(df[rep(1:nrow(df), n), ], index = rep(1:n, each = nrow(df)))
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way

```
n <- 3
map_dfr(seq_len(n), ~ df %>% mutate(index = .x))

  x y index
1 1 a     1
2 2 b     1
3 3 c     1
4 1 a     2
5 2 b     2
6 3 c     2
7 1 a     3
8 2 b     3
9 3 c     3
```